# Overlay two images without losing the intensity of the color using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, image, opencv

How can i overlay two images without losing the intensity of the colors of the two images.

I have Image1 and Image2:

1. [image] 2. [image]

I tried using 0.5 alpha and beta but it gives me a merged image with half the color intensity

```
dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.5,img2,0.5,0)
```

[image]

but when i try using 1 to both alpha and beta channels, it only gives me the merged regions.

```
 dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1,1,img2,1,0)
```

[image]

I have to get an output that looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you add your original image too?

Comment: i added original image1 and image2

Comment: In `BGR`, `purple(255, 0, 255) = blue(255, 0, 0) + red(0, 0, 255)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the `dst` is created based on following formula:

```
dst = src1*alpha + src2*beta + gamma
```

Which says that when you multiply your images that are in fact 3D arrays with `alpha` you are multiplying all the items. For example, for a blue pixel you have `[255, 0, 0]` and the white `[255, 255, 255]`, and when you are adding the matrices together, if you want the result to be blue you should convert the white pixels to 0 which is in fact black (doesn't make sense from physics perspective tho lol). You can simply find the white pixels using *advanced numpy indexing* then convert them to zero.

```
import cv2    

img1 = cv2.imread('img1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.png')

img1[img1[:, :, 1:].all(axis=-1)] = 0
img2[img2[:, :, 1:].all(axis=-1)] = 0

dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1, 1, img2, 1, 0)

cv2.imshow('sas', dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `dst = img1 + img2` should work well after setting the white to black, and it's easier / shorter

Comment: @Miki Indeed, I just wanted to give a general answer, specially close to OP's intend.

Comment: Thank you so much! but how can i set the black back to white on dst? thank you so much!

Comment: @MonTolentino There is no black in `dst` any more. It's blue, purple and red. Because you mixed the images.

Comment: But it'll have on the image i am working on, i have to set all the black pixels to white again. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok i did it using 
img[np.where((img == [0,0,0]).all(axis = 2))] = [255,255,255]