# How to convert (1024,1024) shape image to (1024,1024,3) in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a single channel image with shape (1024,1024).

I want to overlay it with a color image of shape (1024,1024,3) using
`dst = cv2.addWeighted(im, 1, newimg, 1, 0)`

So First, I want to know, how can I convert newimg to 1024x1024x3...Because `im` is of shape 1024x1024x3

Comment: Here is one approach I found by Googling: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-a-grayscale-image-to-an-RGB-image-in-Python. Here is another using numpy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463019/how-to-copy-numpy-array-value-into-higher-dimensions

Comment: Here is my comment again, but without the link. But see my answer below also. ---  Have you considered just doing a Google search before asking on this forum? That often will find numerous solutions to most problems, for example, that type of questions has been asked before on this forum and elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be one simple solution using numpy.

```
Create a 3-channel black image

Put your same grayscale image into each channel
```

```
newimage = np.zeros((grayimage.shape[0],grayimage.shape[1],3))
newimage[:,:,0] = grayimage
newimage[:,:,1] = grayimage
newimage[:,:,2] = grayimage
```

See [how to copy numpy array value into higher dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463019/how-to-copy-numpy-array-value-into-higher-dimensions)

Comment: Worked. Can you also answer how to overlay two cv2 images? I tried `dst = cv2.addWeighted(im, 1, newimage, 1, 0)`

Comment: but got this error `error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:687: error: (-5:Bad argument) Whn the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 'cv::arithm_op'`

Comment: Googling again gives numerous examples using addWeight. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dc4/tutorial_adding_images.html and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/07/transparent-overlays-with-opencv/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250226/overlay-two-images-without-losing-the-intensity-of-the-color-using-opencv-and-py.  Be sure both images have the same size (width and height and channels) and type. It looks like the message is saying that your two images have different types.

Comment: What about types? Is one float and the other 8-bit? What image formats are you input images? How have you read them in? Please show your code. That is important for this forum. See the help section on how to ask a good question and what are good questions. The link is under the ? button at the top right corner of the window.

Comment: `newimage = np.dstack((grey, grey, grey))` is about 8x faster, but if OP already has **OpenCV** installed then `newimage = cv2.cvtColor(grey,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` is around 30x faster - because of SIMD optimisation.

Comment: Many ways to "skin the cat"! Thanks for pointing others out along with speed comparisons, Mark.

Comment: If your single channel grayscale image is `image` with shape `(1024,1024)`. I believe another approach is `result = cv2.merge([image, image, image])`. This should result in shape `(1024,1024,3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower_blue, upper_blue)
print(mask.shape)
mask2 = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
print(mask2.shape)

Output:
(480, 640)
(480, 640, 3)
```

This converts image into 3 channel.